# Creating JXCore application with OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, hosting, openshift

Is it possible to create an **JXCore** application with OpenShift **free plan**?

I know it does support the node.js and the [JXCore](http://jxcore.com/) (open source) stands for:

> JXcore extends Node.JS™ with additional features for developing mobile and embedded applications using JavaScript and leveraging the Node ecosystem.

**If not, are there any free hosting alternatives for JXCore applications?** I know plenty of free PHP web servers, but almost none for node.js/JXCore.

Comment: have you tried it? What errors did you get trying to run your code on OpenShift?

Comment: OpenShift simply does not have an JXCore files (`jx.exe` etc.). As far as I can see it supports `node.js` only.

Comment: OpenShift Online runs on Linux (RHEL specifically).  If JXCore is only available using a .exe file, then no, it will not run on OpenShift, as .exe files are usually Windows specific.